# Кракозябры вместо кириллицы в phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

У меня в бд, при создании новой строки через mysql, вместе кириллицы появляются какие-то кракозябры. При этом, на самом сайте всё нормально

[image: бд]

[image: сайт]

Код подключения к бд:

```
<?php
  $start = filter_var($_POST['start'],
  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

  $end = filter_var($_POST['end'],
  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

  $title = filter_var($_POST['title'],
  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

  $subtitle = filter_var($_POST['description'],
  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

  $mysql = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'event');
  $mysql->query("INSERT INTO `event_calendar` (`start`, `end`, `title`, `description`)
  VALUES('$start', '$end', '$title', '$subtitle')");

  $mysql->close();

  header('Location: index.php');
 ?>
```

Кодировка страницы: utf-8

Кодировка в бд: utf8_general_ci

Ставил mysqli_set_charset('utf8');

Но выдаёт такую ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Структура таблицы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажите скриншот раздела структура этой таблицы. Где-то закралась кодировка/сравнение latin1_general_ci... Скорее всего в настройках подключения к серверу MySQL...

Comment: @andrew-hobbit добавил скрин

Comment: На стартовой странице phpmyadmin показывается кодировка по умолчанию при подключении к серверу БД. Что там у Вас?

Comment: @andrew-hobbit там так же utf8_general_ci

Comment: ну неужели так сложно набрать свой вопрос в гугле?

Comment: ну и конечно рекомендую посмотреть в том же гугле про SQL инъекции